# Convert from Devnet to Mainnet-beta with Metaplex and Sugar

Tags: metaplex, devnet, mint, sugar

This aligns with Solana but also a reference to Metaplex.  Hoping someone can answer as the information found online is slim to none.

I have a project ready to go.  Using Metaplex w/ Solana CLI.  It's currently set on devnet with QuickNode as my RPC.  I want to convert this project to the Mainnet-beta.

How do I do so?

Can I just edit my .env file, add SOL to my CM wallet and relaunch Sugar (Metaplex)?

What steps do I need to take my complete Devnet project and make it live on the mainnet?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The Steps are Exactly the same with Devnet and Mainnet-beta. There are just few things to keep in mind. The RPC should be pointing to mainnet and there should be a wallet with real SOL.